# Add action to a JButton created by another JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a Jbutton that when pressed creates another button and the new button is added to the panel. How to I add an actionListener to the new button?

For example:

```
JButton button = new JButton("lala");
button.addActionListener(this);

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
        if (event.getSource() == button)
        {
          JButton newButton = new JButton("ahah");
          newButton.addActionListener(this);
        }
       }
```

I want to add action to the newButton, how do I do it?

**EDITED CODE:**

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
  if (event.getSource() == button)
    {
      String name = tfOne.getText();
      Icon flag = new ImageIcon("flag/"+name+".png");
      JButton[] newButton = new JButton[click]; 
      newButton[click-1] = new JButton(name, flag);
      p2.add(newButton[click-1]);
      newButton[click-1].addActionListener(new aListener());
      p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5+click,1)); //p2 is a panel that has been created
      setSize(500,450+(click*20));

      click++; //number of times the button is pressed
    }
  }

  public class aListener extends MouseAdapter
  { 
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
      tfOne.setText("lala");
    }
  }
```

The code is not well organized but that's more or less what I want to do

Comment: No, your `aListener` class must implement `ActionListnere`, since you are doing `addActionListener(...)`OR you write `newButton[click - 1].addMouseListener(new aListener());` to make it work.

Comment: Ah indeed. You're calling addActionListener, but it should be addMouseListener on the button that wants the aListener class, or you can have the class implement ActionListener instead of extending MouseAdapter, but then you need to change the method to public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) instead of mouseClicked

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  But in brief: 1) Application resources are usually only accessible via URL, while the `ImageICon` constructor that accepts a `String` interprets it as a `File` path. 2) It seems the entire logic of this GUI is suspicious.  What is it intended to achieve?  3) The layout is more likely to honor the preferred size of a component, than the size.  But set the preferred size with extreme caution, it is not something to do lightly. 4) Add an `ActionListener` rather than a `MouseListener` to buttons.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to have a inner class containg the listener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    if (event.getSource() == button)
    {
      JButton newButton = new JButton("ahah");
      newButton.addMouseListener(new yourListener());
    }
   }  

//add this class as a inner class
   public class aListener extends MouseAdapter
   { 
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
      {
         JButton buttonReference=(JButton)e.getSource(); // you want this since hardcoding the name of the button is bad if you want listeners for more then one button
         buttonReference.setText("lala");
      }
    }
```

This will create a instance of yourListener, and add that to the button when you click it

Comment: But where do I place the inner class? is it out of the actionPerformed() method?

Comment: yes, you place it outside actionPreformed, just as you normally do with a inner class. I usually place my inner listeners last in my class (after all methods)

Comment: I am probably doing something wrong, it is giving me an error:


1 error found:
File: C:\Users\Gonçalo\Desktop\MAIN PROJECTS\File Project\EUCountriesGUI.java  [line: 139]
Error: C:\Users\Gonçalo\Desktop\MAIN PROJECTS\File Project\EUCountriesGUI.java:139: addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener) in javax.swing.AbstractButton cannot be applied to (EUCountriesGUI.aListener)

Comment: Try edit your post with some code, or post a new question and I can take a look at it

Comment: Ok, I went thru the code you posted line by line. As far as I can tell everything seems fine. Don't think this is a issue, but test to create a refrence to the button you add to the array with buttons. E.i JButton button = new JButton(name, flag); newButton[click-1]=button;  Appart from that, make sure that the listener class is declared outside the constructor, and outside of any method. Also i've edited the listener class a bit that will work if you add the listener to more then one button so check my post

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson : That code he pasted is not right, he is doing `newButton[click - 1].addActionListener(new aListener())`, but `aListener` class extends `MouseAdapter`, it never implements `ActionListener`, which is why the OP is getting this error. What the OP should be doing is `newButton[click - 1].addMouseListener(new aListener())`, to make this work. Moreover his/her's logic is too bad, regarding the creation of a new button. You also need to make that correction in your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

For each button you can create it's own `actionPerformed(...)` method, as described in the example below :
Do you mean to do this :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonAction
{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton updateButton;
    private int count = 0;
    private ActionListener updateListener = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            final JButton button = new JButton("" +  count); 
            button.setActionCommand("" + count);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    System.out.println("My COMMAND is : " + event.getActionCommand());
                }
            });
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    contentPane.add(button);
                    contentPane.revalidate();
                    contentPane.repaint();
                }
            });
            count++;
        }
    };

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BUTTON ACTIONS");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));

        updateButton = new JButton("UPDATE GUI");
        updateButton.addActionListener(updateListener);

        frame.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(updateButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new ButtonAction().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `newButton` instance needs to have its `actionPerformed` method filled out. I see that you have an `ActionListener` added to the button, but that just means that someone is listing for actions. The code you show above doesn't define any actions on that `newButton`, so therefore there's no events being fired, and the `ActionListener` never gets notified of anything.