# How to access AbstractButton's method from anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

Here is my class:

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {
    public ButtonPanel () {
        makeButton ("button1");
        makeButton ("button2");
        makeButton ("button3");
    }

    void makeButton (String name) {
        JButton button =new JButton(name);
        add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setText("I was clicked");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, its text should change to "I was clicked". However, I don't know how to access the `setText` method. I tried `button.setText("I was clicked")` but this is not possible.

Comment: Please do have a look at the updated answer of mine, for some more help, though I am still looking for the explanation I had posted once, as to why we need to make it final. As I will get that info, I will post that for your help too :-)

Comment: Please find the updated answer, that might be able to explain a bit about the reason for using a `final` in this situation.

Comment: Thank you so much!.That's an elaborate description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By making the reference of `JButton` as final, like :

```
void makeButton(String name)
{
    final JButton button =new JButton(name);
    add(button);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            button.setText("I was clicked");
        }
    });
}
```

Here is one related example :

[Add action to a Button created by another Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824555/1057230)

---

### EDIT 1:

Here is one updated version of your code, that works as mentioned before :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonExample1 extends JPanel {

    private JButton makeButton (String name) {
        final JButton button =new JButton(name);
        add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setText("I was clicked");
            }
        });

        return button;
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(makeButton("One"));
        contentPane.add(makeButton("Two"));
        contentPane.add(makeButton("Three"));       

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);  
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ButtonExample1().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT 2 :

Here is the answer that tries to explain a reason, why you need to declare it as `final`

To answer your question, you need to understand the basics, as to how the JVM use to work.
When the classes are compiled which contain inner classes, the byte code which gets generated does not actually implement inner classes as a class within a class.

**WHY THE ERROR : The local variable was accessed from an inner class, needs to declare it final**

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class foo extends JPanel
{  
  public foo()
  {
    final JMenu edit = new JMenu();
    edit.getItem(0).addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){ 
    @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                edit.getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
            }
        } 
    });
  }
}
```

When you compile your this program, two files will be created, Foo.class and Foo$1.class. So now your problem comes, since the `Second` class i.e. `foo$1.class` doesn't know that `Variable` <kbd>edit</kbd> is present inside the `First` class i.e. `foo.class`.

So how to solve this problem ? What `JVM` does, is that, ***It makes a requirement for the developer to make the variable of an outer class to be declared as final***.

Now this being done, now JVM quietly places a hidden variable with the name val$edit  inside the 2nd compiled class file, here is the output as got from `javap`

Ouput for foo.class

```
C:\Mine\JAVA\J2SE\folder>javap foo.class
Compiled from "foo.java"
public class foo extends javax.swing.JPanel {
  public foo();
}
```

Now since, edit is local to the constructor, hence the output as above.

```
C:\Mine\JAVA\J2SE\folder>javap foo$1.class
Compiled from "foo.java"
class foo$1 extends java.awt.event.MouseAdapter {
  final javax.swing.JMenu val$edit;
  final foo this$0;
  foo$1(foo, javax.swing.JMenu);
  public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent);
}
```

The `Variable` val$edit is assigned the same value which has been assigned to edit since now the compiler knows that the value cannot be changed as it has been declared final and hence it works this time.

Now what if I change the <kbd>edit</kbd> `Variable` from being `Local` to being `Instance`. Now the object of the class knows everything about this variable <kbd>edit</kbd>, if it gets changed. So changing the above program likewise we get :

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class foo extends JPanel
{  
    JMenu edit = new JMenu();

    public foo()
    {   
        edit.getItem(0).addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){ 
        @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
            {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    edit.getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
                }
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

Here in this case, we are not suppose to declare and define it as being `final`, because in this case since the `Variable` being Local to the whole class, the `Variable` is send to the Inner Class along with the `Object Reference` i.e. `this`

```
C:\Mine\JAVA\J2SE\folder>javap foo.class
Compiled from "foo.java"
public class foo extends javax.swing.JPanel {
  javax.swing.JMenu edit;
  public foo();
}
```

Here is how the `Variable` is send in this case i.e. this$0 :

```
C:\Mine\JAVA\J2SE\folder>javap foo$1.class
Compiled from "foo.java"
class foo$1 extends java.awt.event.MouseAdapter {
  final foo this$0;
  foo$1(foo);
  public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent);
}
```

Seems like that the interpretation, how this situation works, according to me.
Just now I found this wonderful explanation on the internet regarding [Mystery of Accessibility in Local Inner Classes](http://techtracer.com/2008/04/14/mystery-of-accessibility-in-local-inner-classes/), might be this will help you understand the situation in a much better way :-)

Comment: But iam unsure how it affects the behaviour of a component if it is declared final.There is information about final class,method and variable. But i cannot find information about final component.

Comment: Since you are using the variable of the outer class, inside inner class, hence for scope reasons you have to make it `final`. I am finding a good explanation regarding the same.

Comment: A `final` component only means that the reference to the component will not change in the current scope. In this answer's code example, it means that `button` will always point to the same `JButton` instance while the `makeButton` method is being executed.

Comment: @Laf: Yes, but not quite.  The Java Memory Model also contains a treatment of the use of the `final` keyword that pertains to "Initialisation Safety".  This is germane mainly to multithreaded applications accessing shared state variables.  I think that the statement that "the `final` keyword can alter or increase the scope of local variables" is possibly incorrect or specious.